# Error running bash script - No matching processes

Tags: macos, bash, kill

I am trying to kill Xcode by running `killall Xcode.app`, which works normally when I run it through terminal. However, if I put it into a bash script that I keep on my Desktop called `re_xcode`, the script will output the following error. Please can you tell me where I am going wrong?

> No matching processes belonging to you were found
>
> The file /Users/Max/Desktop/Applications/Xcode.app does not exist.

```
#!/bin/bash
killall Xcode.app
open ./Applications/Xcode.app
```

Comment: -1 Two fundamental flaws in two commands leads me to believe you did not research before posting. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Two mistakes:

1. `killall` takes a process name as an argument. `Xcode.app` however is an application bundle. It contains much more than just the process, including all kinds of files that also belong to an application (graphics, translation data, et cetera).

   Thus, the actual way to kill Xcode would be:

   ```
   killall Xcode
   ```

   Or, in a sane way, using AppleScript:

   ```
   osascript -e 'tell app "Xcode" to quit'
   ```
2. Your other error is that `.` references the directory your current script resides in, which could be anything. In your case, it's the desktop. Thus, your `kill` command works fine, but `open` will fail since there's no Xcode (or "applications" folder) on your desktop.

   Xcode doesn't install to `/Developer` anymore. The Mac App Store version is a self-contained application under `/Applications/Xcode.app`. So, you could do:

   ```
   open /Applications/Xcode.app
   ```

   However, the most portable solution would be to just use:

   ```
   open -a Xcode
   ```

   This will open Xcode wherever it's installed since it relies on the LaunchServices database to figure out the correct path.

---

To go even further, rather than doing this as a bash script, why not create an alias in your `.bash_profile`? This will be much simpler to execute anywhere from your command line.

```
alias rex='killall Xcode && open -a Xcode'
```

Comment: You forgot the *matching processed* part, where the user mistakes the app bundle for the executable. `killall` doesn't work fine, at all.

Comment: Oh, right. Well, `killall Xcode` works fine for me – but I guess a `osascript -e 'tell app "Xcode" to quit'` would be a more sane approach.

Comment: Yeah, but `killall Xcode.app` is where the error message in the question comes from.

Comment: True, I somehow overread that and just looked at the script.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running that script from your Desktop, and there it can't find the path to xcode.app. Check the correct location, for me it is `/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app`.